# Django object.get(pk = sth), how to check if input is not malicious

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to see my user by their id vias this route:

```
 path('users/<int:pk>', views.UserDetail.as_view()),
```

and in my view I have this code:

```
users.objects.get(pk=sth)
```

in this case input (sth) will check with all id in the database to check if input Id exists and if not found it will return an error.
the problem is here if the user enters a script that causes erasing the database, I will not know. how can I check from beginning id input data is valid?

Comment: you can try change to `users.objects.filter(id=sth)`. If this return None, this mean not have id exists in database,  you can do anything you want, like raise exception or pass it. If found , it is correct id input, and exists in database

Comment: @NgocPham ok but there is no difference, the input data will be check with all the data in the database and if not exist it return none. what if during this checking the bad input cause database to erase. I want to check input before any objects.get/filter runs

Comment: i think noway to know one `id` exits in database or not if you dont excute query to database. If you worry about after you found it then anybody delete it, try lock this table, dont have anything can update and delete

Comment: @NgocPham you mean using  Read Committed Isolation Level in isolation_level options?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, congratulations for being concerned about security issues, that's something that quite a few "web developpers" seem to totally ignore - alas for us end-users.

And congratulations too for having choosed one the most security-aware web frameworks around - no code is garanteed to be totally secured of course, but with Django just following the official documented way to do things and best practices will already protect your site from most of the known attack vectors (assuming you keep everything - Django etc - up to date and your front server is properly configured of course), and you can count on frequent security releases too when a vulnerability is detected. The only caveat here is about 3rd part django apps that might not be properly coded, so stick with the ones that are well maintained and have a solid userbase and even then make sure you browse their source code for possible flaws.

Now wrt/ your question:

Your 'sth' will already be validated a first time by the urlresolver (the part that dispatches http requests to views according to your urlconf), and given the `'users/<int:pk>'` definition, anything after "users/" that is not an integer (well, that doesn't match the `\d+` regexp) will be rejected, so your view will never be executed at all.

Then, even if it was, the `User.objects.get(pk=sth)` expression will be sanitized a second time by the ORM itself, and here again if `sth` is not valid for the given field the ORM will raise an error so no query will make it to the database - which you can also check by yourself:

```
>>> User.objects.get(pk="delete from auth_user")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 376, in get
    clone = self.filter(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 796, in filter
    return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 814, in _filter_or_exclude
    clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1227, in add_q
    clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1253, in _add_q
    allow_joins=allow_joins, split_subq=split_subq,
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1187, in build_filter
    condition = self.build_lookup(lookups, col, value)
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 1083, in build_lookup
    return final_lookup(lhs, rhs)
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 19, in __init__
    self.rhs = self.get_prep_lookup()
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/lookups.py", line 59, in get_prep_lookup
    return self.lhs.output_field.get_prep_value(self.rhs)
  File "/home/bruno/.virtualenvs/blook/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 946, in get_prep_value
    return int(value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'delete from auth_user'
```

And finally, even if 1/ your url was defined to accept just anything as param and 2/ you were doing a query on a varchar or text field, the orm will make proper use of your database connector module by using a [parameterized SQL query](http://bobby-tables.com/python) so the database connector will ALSO sanitize the query params, preventing an SQL injection.

As you can see, you would actually have to make quite some efforts to bypass most of Django itself (the urlresolver and the ORM in this case) and deliberately make a wrong use of your database connector module to open your app to an SQL injection.

Comment: Thank you for your time and complete answer:)

Answer (score 5):

You don't have to worry about those scenarios.

More info: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/security/#sql-injection-protection